# C++/QT - File reading stops unexpectedly. Everything else is working as it should

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I have a very strange issue. I have this code, which is supposed to loop until the end of the file. But it only loops exactly two times. It never finishes the while, but it reaches the end of the "if" or "else" sentence (depending on the file content).
Everything else is working "good", the numbers that are supposed to be going in are going in, and everything seems to be working until it doesn't reach the end of the while.
This is a futoshiki game. The code is supposed to read each line, treat it as a string, and then break it down into chars, which in turn are casted into integers (except for one char, being a less-than or greater-than sign), which make up the position of the cells or the positions between the signs. Then it uses that data to either add a new cell to the board or a new sign between cells.
The first line of a file is the size of the board.
This issue happens with several different files of different sizes, always on the second iteration. I'm running Linux by the way if it makes any difference.

```
int MainWindow::charToInt(char letter)
{
    int number = letter;
    return number - 48;
}

void MainWindow::locateInBoard(string data, board gameboard)
{
    if (data.size()==3){
        int number = charToInt(data[2]);
        pair<int,int> coordinate(charToInt(data[0]), charToInt(data[1]));
        gameboard.addCell(number,true,coordinate);
    }
    else{
        pair<int,int> firstCoordinate(charToInt(data[0]), charToInt(data[1]));
        pair<int,int> secondCoordinate(charToInt(data[2]), charToInt(data[3]));
        gameboard.addSign(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate, data[4]);
    }
}

void MainWindow::getBoardFromFile(QString newString, board* ptToBoard)
/*
    Each board has a file. The name of the file is determined by the size of the
    board to play, the difficulty and the number of board. The text file contains the
    sign and numbers of the board. Let's say the number 3 is in position (2,1), then the
    file should contain a line "213". For signs, if there is a > between (3,3) and (3,4),
    the file should have a line "3334>"
*/
{
    QFile file(newString);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        return;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    QString line = in.readLine();
    size = line.toInt();
    board gameboard(size);
    string stdline;
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        line = in.readLine();
        stdline = line.toStdString();
        locateInBoard(stdline,gameboard);
    }
    *ptToBoard = gameboard;
}
```

And this is the relevant code of "board".

```
board::board(int n)
{
    boardSize = n;
    gameboard = new cell*[boardSize];
    for (int i = 0; i<boardSize; i++){
        gameboard [i] = new cell[boardSize];
    }
    pair<int,int> newPosition;
    for (int i = 0; i<boardSize; i++){
        newPosition.first = i;
        for (int j = 0; j<boardSize; j++){
            newPosition.second = j;
            gameboard[i][j].setPosition(newPosition);
        }
    }
}

void board::addCell(int number, bool fixed, pair<int,int> position)
{
    cell newCell(number,fixed,position);
    gameboard[position.first][position.second] = newCell;
}

void board::addSign(pair<int,int> firstPosition, pair<int,int> secondPosition, char sign)
{
    cell firstCell = gameboard[firstPosition.first][firstPosition.second];
    cell secondCell = gameboard[secondPosition.first][secondPosition.second];
    gameRules.setUnequality(firstCell,secondCell,sign);
}
```

I know it's not pretty, but I should've handed this in Wednesday and it's three am Thursday and I really don't care anymore if it's pretty or hard-coded as long as it's working.

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm really desperate here.

Comment: Any chance that the file has a Ctrl-Z embedded in it? That will cause premature end-of-file under Windows in Text mode.

Comment: No, no chance. I'm running Linux, and it happens with several different files, all on the second iteration. I'll add that to the original post. I checked them just in case... not sure how to do that, but I opened them in nano and several editors? Didn't see anything.

Comment: I suppose spewing `stdline ` out to `std::cerr` for each line, preceded by the filename its pulled from, has been tried ? (or isn't relevant; sry, not a Qt programmer, so kinda working with what I got here). Seeing that along side the actual file content may prove helpful. Coupled with temporarily commenting out the call to `locateInBoard` and just seeing how well/if the loop carries through the end of the file may prove educational.

Comment: It looks like you're passing the game board to locateInBoard by value instead of by pointer or reference. Also, I'm a little suspicious of `*ptToBoard = gameboard` -- does your Board class have the right copy semantics to make this work?

Comment: I'm using qtDebug() for debugging, that's what seemed so strange. It breaks right after the locateInBoard.

Comment: AlexP, you were right about both. I needed to reference it, it's working now. If you want you can answer the question instead of commenting so I can vote it as the best answer. (I think it works like that? Sorry, first time here). Thanks so much, really!
Sadly now it's not reaching the end of the

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit my prior comment right now. Ignore everything from "Sadly" onwards.

Comment: @AlexP Make that an answer and I'll uptick. Hopefully Paula will as well if still watching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the signature of your `locateInBoard` method:

```
void MainWindow::locateInBoard(string data, board gameboard)
```

That's passing the board *by value*. So all changes made to the board in `locateInBoard` are applied to a local copy, which will just get thrown away when the function completes.

Try pass-by-reference instead:

```
void MainWindow::locateInBoard(string data, board & gameboard)
```

---

In addition, I'm worried about this:

```
board gameboard(size); // created locally
// ... lots of processing ...
*ptToBoard = gameboard; // copy using assignment operator
```

This is something that *can* work, but you have to make sure your `board` class correctly supports copying data. C++ generates default assignment operators if you don't write your own, but they don't work for anything other than trivial structures. You'll likely need to [implement your own assignment operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) or change your code to avoid using assignment or a copy constructor.

Here's a quick alternative that avoids needing to figure out how to write your own `operator=`:

```
board * MainWindow::getBoardFromFile(QString newString)
{
    // ...
    board * gameboard = new board(size);
    // ... do all of your stuff ...
    // you'll need to change your existing code to use -> instead of .
    // if you get an error, return 0 or throw an exception
    return gameboard;
}
```

(If you don't want to support copy constructors and `operator=`, it's good practice to write your own anyway — just make them do nothing and markthem private in your header. This'll allow the compiler to help you catch unintended copying.)